# How to make a for-loop out of this?

Tags: vba, excel

How should be the for-loop if I am trying to generalize this :

given `Number = 3`

```
FirstCellToWrite.Value = Controls("txtBox" & 1).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 0).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 2).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 0).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 3).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(0, 1).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 4).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 1).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 5).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 1).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 6).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(0, 2).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 7).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 2).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 9).Text
   FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 2).Value = Controls("txtBox" & 8).Text
```

What I tried is:

```
  q= 0
  For p = 1 To number
  For i = 0 To number - 1

  FirstCellToWrite.Offset(i, q).Value = Controls("txtBox" & p).Text

   Next i
   q = q+1
   Next p
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 3):

Try it without q or i and some maths on p.

```
For p = 0 To number - 1
    debug.print "i=" & p mod 3 & ", q=" & int(p/3) & ", p=" & p+1
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(p mod 3, int(p/3)).Value = Controls("txtBox" & p+1).Text
Next p
```

Immediate window results:

```
i=0, q=0, p=1
i=1, q=0, p=2
i=2, q=0, p=3
i=0, q=1, p=4
i=1, q=1, p=5
i=2, q=1, p=6
i=0, q=2, p=7
i=1, q=2, p=8
i=2, q=2, p=9
```

Comment: Nice use of `mod`. Hadn't thought of using the output for the row value

Answer (score 2):

If you simplify it less, using just 1 loop:

```
For p = 0 To (number-1)\3 'Using \ instead of / returns just the integer part
'i.e. 1/2 = 0.5, 1\2 = 0 and 5/2 = 2.5, 5\2 = 2
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(0, p).Value = Controls("txtBox" & (3*p + 1)).Text
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, p).Value = Controls("txtBox" & (3*p + 2)).Text
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, p).Value = Controls("txtBox" & (3*p + 3)).Text
Next p
```

Then it becomes easier to see how  you can make the inside a second loop:

```
For p = 0 To (number-1)\3
    For i=1 To 3
        FirstCellToWrite.Offset(i-1, p).Value = Controls("txtBox" & (3*p + i)).Text
    Next i
Next p
```

Comment: Ah - I had overlooked the `number=3` bit.  This is code for `number=8` - if you've already divided into rows, just remove the `\3`

Comment: when i use \3 it will add only first two column values... actually i have 3 columns. but when I remove \3 all data gets entered..but it is throwing error after that.. Runtime error couldnot specify the object

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like the following:

```
Dim ctrl As Long, RowCount As Long, ColumnCount As Long, IncrementCounter As Long

IncrementCounter = 3
For ctrl = 1 To 9
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value2 = Controls("txtBox" & ctrl).Text
    RowCount = RowCount + 1

    If ctrl Mod IncrementCounter = 0 Then
        ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
        RowCount = 0
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your p and q should be the other way around:
`FirstCellToWrite.Offset(i,p).value = Controls("txtBox" & q).Text`

And the `q = q + 1` should be between the "i" for loop.

Comment: `FirstCellToWrite.Offset(i, p).Value = Controls("txtBox" & q).Text` this giving empty while debugging